# How to call WebMatrix Helper function from jQuery AJAX?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, webmatrix

I have a helper method inside my App_Code folder which returns some html to be displayed on the page. How can I do jQuery/AJAX request to call that method (passing an int as a parameter) and have the HTML returned so I can display it on the page?

I've been looking everywhere and have absolutely no idea where to even start. I'd appreciate any help at all.

Comment: You cannot do that because simply said: c# code happens at the server side and JavaScript happens at the client side. Or was that not your question?

Comment: @Silvermind That's what I previously thought. But, I came across an article that shows (and works) you how to call a WebMethod from jQuery/AJAX which is inside an aspx page which returns a value. But, my situation is only slightly different. In my case, instead of calling a method that is in an ASPX page, I need to call a method that is inside a App_Code/myHelper.cs file.

Comment: cite: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: I've spent weeks trying to get my way to work for me. So far with no luck. But, all I am trying to do is AJAX some stuff onto my page. I just need to be able to render some HTML based on some results that come from a database (ajax, no page refreshing) - I don't care if it isn't a helper file, just as long as it's ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another page that uses the Helper to render HTML, and provide a value via the AJAX call. For example, you might have a page called RenderHelper.cshtml:

```
@{
    var i = Request["id"].AsInt();
}

@Helpers.MyMethod(i)
```

Then in your calling page, use the jQuery load function:

```
$('#elementToFill').load('RenderHelper/?id=' + some_int);
```

Comment: could you please elaborate? I'm a little confused by `Add another page` (sorry) - I think, -sorry, I'm really confused but I'm pretty sure I get it.

Comment: this isn't working; do you have any resources/docs I could look at?

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"? The code I provided is illustrative only. It isn't meant to work as-is. You need to change "myMethod" to the name of your helper method, and you need to change "#elementToFill" to the id of the element that you want to display the HTML in, and finally, you need to change "some_int" to represent the value of the integer that your helper expects. It's difficult to point you at suitable resources when I don't know what it is that you don't know.

Comment: I just noticed that your helper file is called myHelper.cs. That is not a Web Pages (WebMatrix) helper file. See this: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/173/The-Difference-Between-@Helpers-and-@Functions-In-WebMatrix.  Are you using ASP.NET Web Pages or Web Forms?

Comment: Correct, .cs is not a helper file, it's just a typo in my question; my actual helper file is .cshtml.

I managed to get it to work, though it keeps displaying the header and footer from the layout.cshtml page. Is there a way to disable that stuff just for this page?

Comment: To disable layout, `Layout = null;` works perfectly. Thanks for your help Mike! :-) I'm glad you helped, it's put an end to a long struggle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use web service.

Call your class methods int the web service and call web service using jQuery/Ajax.

For eg.

**Class file**

```
Class MyClass
{
public static string GetName(string Name)
{
return "My name is "+Name;
}
}
```

**Web service**

```
[WebService(Namespace = "WebService")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class YourNameIs : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
        public string GetName(string Name)
        {
            return MyClass.GetName(Name);
        }

    }
```

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax(
    {
        Type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "WebService.asmx/GetName",
        data: '{Name: "' + name + '"}',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d); //set msg to any div elemts InnerHTML like $("#yourDivElement").html(msg.d);
        }
    });
```

I didn't tested the code, hope it will give an idea.

Comment: Thank you user, much appreciated. I've never been able to get any webservice to work with this particular web host I have, but it's still nice work, I may use it for another site in the future.